# Integrating out the 5th dimension in AdS/CFT

Tags: string-theory, ads-cft, branes

My main understanding of AdS/CFT is through the idea that the partition functions on the boundary and bulk are equivalent when expressed in terms of source fields $J_0$. On the boundary $J_0$ is a source for some dual operator field $O$, and in the bulk it is the the boundary condition for a bulk field $J$.

But the philosophy in some papers seems to be different. For example in the QCD model of Sakai, Sugimoto ([arXiv:hep-th/0412141](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.hep-th/0412141)), the authors do begin with a bulk spacetime that is supposed to be dual to pure Yang-Mills (at least in some limit which we are not quite able to take) in the sense of the first paragraph. But then to introduce quarks they consider a configuration of probe branes in this bulk spacetime background, and they seem to treat the probe branes with a different approach.

They consider the Dirac-Born-Infeld (DBI) action of the probe branes which is expressed in terms of gauge fields living on the brane and some scalars representing fluctuation of the position of the brane. The DBI action is truncated to low order in powers of the fields and the action is integrated over the 5th coordinate to get a 4 dimensional action that looks like the Skyrme model.

My question is about this last step. It doesn't seem to agree with the relation in the first paragraph. The four dimensional fields found by directly integrating over the bulk action seem to be like the $J_0$ fields, but the action on the boundary side ought to be expressed in terms of the $O$ fields. Why is this justified, or what am I misunderstanding?